# How can I include a class to aspx.cs file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, namespaces

I can't use a simple class in aspx.cs file. I know i should include some code to declare this class before creating an instance like

```
User user = new User();
```

, but I don't know the syntax. I'm new to C# and ASP.net, as you see, and can have other errors in logic so any help is appreciated

**This is how my website structure looks like:**

[image: This is how my website structure looks like]

This is the code of User.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


public class User
{

  public int Id 
  {
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; } 
  }

  public String Username
  {
    get { return username; }
    set { username = value; }
  }

  public String Password
  {
    get { return password; }
    set { password = value; }
  }

}
```

**This is the code of Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(!IsPostBack)
      {
        doSomething();
      }
    }

    private void doSomething() {
      User user = new User(); // error is shown
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> placing cursor in the user and you will get help on that.

### Edit 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DBConnection.model.business
{
    public class User
    {
    ...
```

Then using like below in your default.aspx

```
using DBConnection.model.business;
```

You can get the reference of your class.

Comment: It works, but why I have to place my class in App_Code directory, can't I store it in my own?

Comment: you don't need to place it inside `App_code`. But make sure you add your class inside that folder by right clicking on the folder and creating new class file. This will generate a `name space` your root folder till the folder where you added your class like `DBConnection.model.business`

Comment: When class is in `App_code` no errors, when it is in another directory, there is an error. And I have done everything as you said

Comment: `App_Code` is directly accessible anywhere in the project. It's a special folder provided by the framework.

Comment: Then what can be the reason of my problem? :(

Comment: The problem was there is no name space above your class your class should be inside a namespace see the edits

Answer (score 1):

Add **using DBConnection.model.business;**

or

1. Point user object and click mouse right click
2. Select resolve
3. [image]

Comment: An error appears on this line: "The type or namespace name 'DBConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: The class was defined without a namespace, so this doesn't work.

Comment: @AnthonyChu I put the class inside namespace DBConnection
{ 
  ...
} ,
the same error

Comment: When class is in App_code there are no errors, when it is in another directory, there is an error. Both of you are suggesting the same and likely the right thing, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @gdrt94, read this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx